# knockout - binding multiple variables on dynamic element

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, websocket

**Req:**

- I've a websocket which pumps array of key values.
- Browser side, when websocket messages received , different types of real-time graphs should be drawn

**Current status:**

- I've implemented different graphs and binding with web socket streaming using knock out custom handler bindings (to draw different graphs).

**My Question is:**

- Currently one value is drawn on each graph.
- But i neeed multiple values should be drawn on same graph.

Technically that's possible from Graphing library side. Only thing is i need call custom binding handler every time any one of the values of any graph came from websocket.

**Edit:**

> I made a sample code which i'm looking to implement same using
>   KnockOut. Currently i did using js & small jQuery script.

```
HTML:
   <div class="element" id="container"></div>
   <button id="StartTrigger">Start</button>
   <button id="StopTrigger">Stop</button>
JS:
  var timer = null;

function startTimer() {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
    drawGraph({
        'x001': Math.floor(Math.random() * 11),
            'x002': Math.floor(Math.random() * 11),
            'x003': Math.floor(Math.random() * 11),
            'x004': Math.floor(Math.random() * 11),
            'x005': Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)
    });
  }, 1000);
  }

  function stopTimer() {
        clearInterval(timer);
  }

  $(function (e) {
     $("#StartTrigger").on("click", startTimer);
     $("#StopTrigger").on("click", stopTimer);
  });

  function drawGraph(obj) {
     $("#container").text(obj.x001 + " " + obj.x004);
  }
```

> Here is the fiddle with the same.
>      http://jsfiddle.net/m962dmvL/

So, please guide me to conenct dots using KnockOut.

Comment: A minimal, complete, verifiable example would be useful here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: code sample with fiddle added. please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put additional observables in the binding and access them in `allBindings`.

The final result is the binding is "dependant" on both x001 and x004 (to show it responds to x004 , comment out this line `//self.x001(obj.x001);`)

http://jsfiddle.net/m962dmvL/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="element" data-bind="myGraph: x001, anotherPoint: x004"></div>
```

**JS**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myGraph = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var mainVal = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var additionalVal = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('anotherPoint'));

        $(element).text(mainVal + " " + additionalVal);
    }
};
```

If you have unknown number of data to be drawn, consider using an observableArray. Update the content of the array in your websocket callback as `self.dataArray(newData)`.

Comment: Thanks for answer @huocp. is it possible to extend to dynamic number of anotherPoint? on single element i want to have dynamic number of another points (more than two on single element).

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer, you can hold all points in an observableArray. `data-bind="myGraph: dataArray"`, then additional binding is unnecessary.

Comment: so if i use array, how can i bind few variables of array to element. For Eg: I've array with five variables. out of five, two should be bind to element1 and some other two should be bind to another element and another element bind to some two variables of my data array. all element are dynamic elements (creating on user click).

Comment: you can create as many observableArray as you need, then update them selectively in your websocket callback. `self.dataArray1([newData[0], newData[3]]); self.dataArray2([newData[1], newData[2]]);`.